# NHibernate QueryOver and Collection Filtering

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-3

Simple example of my class:

```cs
public class Post
{
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

User checks few interested tags for filtering Post list.

I need to filter all post by selected tags like:

```cs
Session.QueryOver<Post>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Tags)
    .IsIn(criterion.InterestedTags.ToList())
    .List<Post>();
```

Exception: `NHibernate.QueryException: Cannot use collections with InExpression`

Actually, I should show post if **one of its tag** contains in InterestedTags.

**UPD**

Works for me:

```
Session.QueryOver<Post>()
    .JoinAlias(p => p.Tags, () => tag)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => tag.Id)
    .IsIn(criterion.InterestedTags.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray())
    .List<Post>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use alias to make restrictions on `one-to-many` part

Try following code snippet:

```
Tag tag = null; 
Session.QueryOver<Post>()
    .JoinAlias(p => p.Tags, () => tag)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => tag.Id)
    .IsIn(criterion.InterestedTags.ToList()) //*
    .List<Post>();
```

*Assuming that `InterestedTags` is collection of identifiers.

Comment: This query throws [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

But works if change to:

Session.QueryOver<Post>()
    .JoinAlias(p => p.Tags, () => tag)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => tag.Id)
    .IsIn(criterion.InterestedTags.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray())
    .List<Post>();

Comment: You need to select the exact field to compare. In this case the ID. So in the IsIn method we need the Id. IsIn(criterion.InterestedTags.Select(x => x.Id)).ToList()